# Paw.app -> how to see what TLS settings were used?

Tags: https, httprequest, httpresponse

I can easily see this in my browser:

[image]

I can also see the same with cURL's verbose flag:
`curl -v https://rustymagnet3000.local/hello`

Comment: Unfortunately, Paw does not yet implement this. We had some requests for a way to visualize the TLS/SSL certificate and cyphers used for the connection. We are planning to add this in a future release of Paw!

Comment: any word on this feature @MichaMazaheri?  Paw 3.1.8 does not have this feature.

Comment: Any updates paw? Its 2020 yet